# Meaning of そ、in 「そ、　そんなこと言っても……」?

Tags: translation, words, definitions

I need some help understanding what "そ," means in the following context, in which two fighters are being forced to fight and are conversing during the fight:

> Opponent:「死にたくなかったら、　本気できなさい」
>
> “If you don’t want to die, then fight seriously.”
>
> POV character:「そ、　そんなこと言っても……」

I managed to translate most of the Point Of View character's response; but I don't know what そ could mean in the above sentence. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a "stutter" of the first mora of そんな, meant to convey hesitation or a lack of confidence.

Comment: How would you translate it as? A repetition of the first word used, or as something else?
Ex: “But... but to say such a thing……”
or
“Even... even if you say such a thing……”

Comment: I believe so, another very common way is to repeat the first letter, like "B-but ... to say such a thing..."